# Bash script to extract all specific key values from a unstructured JSON file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I was trying to extract all the values from a specific key in the below JSON file.

```
{
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "xxx1",
      "image_id": "yyy1"
    },
    {
      "name": "xxx2",
      "image_id": "yyy2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I used the below code to get the image_id key values.

```
echo new.json | jq '.tags[] | .["image_id"]'
```

I'm getting the below error message.

```
parse error: Invalid literal at line 2, column 0
```

I think either the JSON file is not in the proper format OR the echo command to call the Json file is wrong.

Given the above input, my intended/desired output is:

```
yyy1
yyy2
```

What needs to be fixed to make this happen?

Comment: yeah, use `cat` not `echo`.

Comment: Use *triple* backticks on their own lines, not single backticks, when code-formatting a full line or more. You don't get code formatting or modified background coloration (going beyond the region of the window where actual text is written) with single backticks.

Comment: That said, don't use `cat` either. `jq '.tags[] | .["image_id"]' <new.json` is the Right Thing. Unnecessary use of `cat` *sometimes* is nearly harmless (and honestly, this is one of those times), but getting into the habit will bite you hard when the command you're running is `tail`, `shuf`, or something else that's extremely inefficient when given a non-seekable FD.

Comment: BTW, when trying to anonymize content to build a [mcve], be sure it's still syntactically valid enough to fulfill the "verifiable" criteria. When you change a number to `xxx` without quotes, your input is no longer valid JSON, making the reproducer no longer something that can be run without changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run:

```
echo new.json | jq '.tags[] | .["image_id"]'
```

...the string `new.json` -- **not** the contents of the file named `new.json` -- is fed to `jq`'s stdin, and is thus what it tries to parse as JSON text.

[Instead, run:](https://jqplay.org/s/OpJxQ-1mQp)

```
jq -r '.tags[] | .["image_id"]' <new.json
```

...to directly open `new.json` connected to the stdin of `jq` (and, with `-r`, to avoid adding unwanted quotes to the output stream).

Answer (score 0):

1. Your filter `.tags[] | .["image_id"]`

is valid, but can be abbreviated to:

```
.tags[] | .image_id
```

or even:

```
.tags[].image_id
```

2. If you want the values associated with the "image_id" key, wherever that key occurs, you could go with:

   `.. | objects | select(has("image_id")) | .image_id`

Or, if you don't mind throwing away false and null values:

```
.. | .image_id? // empty
```